# GoogleMaps API can't get current latitude and longitude

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the coordinates but without success. The result is 0 . But when I write:

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

I can see the blue dot. I'm trying to get these values with this code:

```
lat = googleMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude();
lng = googleMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude();
```

After that, `lat` and `lng` are 0.

My whole code:

```
public class GPS_maps extends Activity {
    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    static Location currentLocation;
    static double lat , lng;
    TextView coordinates;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        coordinates = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_coordinates);
        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {            
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            // googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            lat = googleMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude();
            lng = googleMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude();
            coordinates.setText(String.valueOf(lat) +" , " +String.valueOf(lng));
            LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 5);
            googleMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
       initilizeMap();
    }}
}
```

I don't get any errors. Where is my mistake?

Comment: The map may not have your location at that point in time. Try adding an `onMyLocationChangeListener` to your map and set your location on the first call.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Remove static modifier from the declaration of lat, lan.
Make sure you are sending in the correct syntax to setCoordiante.
To make sure the lat and lan are right, print them out right after you get them.

Comment: removed the static but theres no diffrent still 0

Comment: Print out the vars right after you obtain them. What does it say?

Comment: Also print out the googleMap object to make sure it exists like u want it

Comment: What do you mean with print googleMap object ? And I am printing the vars after I obtain them or not ? What is for you after obtaining ? Where ?

Comment: System.out.println(lat) - do same for long

Comment: Then, also print something that you know is unique about this googleMap object, just to make sure it exists properly